# C3.js PIE not displaying corectly with valid data

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I have simple function:

```
   var Data = $("#orders_data").html(); 
                         
            var c3_orders_chart = c3.generate({

                bindto: '#c3_orders',
                data: {
                     columns: [ Data 

                     ],
                  
                    type : 'pie'
                },


                pie: {
                   
                }
            });
```

**In view:**

```
 <div id="orders_data" style="">
         ['Viriesi', <%= @user_sex_m %>],['Sievietes', <%= @user_sex_w %>]
</div>
```

**In controller:**

```
 @user_sex_w = user_sexshash['totals'][0].floor.to_s
       @user_sex_m = user_sexshash['totals'][1].floor.to_s
```

Result data looks like this:

['Viriesi', 100 ],['Sievietes', 0]

This code generates such PIE:

[image]

But if I change function data to:

```
 var c3_orders_chart = c3.generate({

                    bindto: '#c3_orders',
                    data: {
                         columns: [  
                            ['New', 64],
                            ['In Progrees', 36]

                         ],
                      
                        type : 'pie'
                    },


                    pie: {
                       
                    }
                });
```

PIE looks like it should.

What could possibly cause this issue ? Data type is incorect or what?
I haven't found any similar question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue. In your first example, you have:

```
var Data = $("#orders_data").html();
```

And then:

```
columns: [Data],
```

`Data` is a string because you retrieved it with the `.html()` method. It's the literal string:

```
"['Viriesi', 100 ],['Sievietes', 0]"
```

This is not actually an array which you were expecting. What you need to do is make that string parse-able JSON.

First, in your view make the text valid JSON (use double quotes, and wrap the 2 columns in an array):

```
<div id="orders_data" style="">
    [["Viriesi", <%= @user_sex_m %>], ["Sievietes", <%= @user_sex_w %>]]
</div>
```

Second, when you get `Data`, parse it as JSON:

```
var Data_string = $("#orders_data").html();
var Data_columns = JSON.parse(Data_string);
```

Then use the parsed `Data_columns` in your chart:

```
var c3_orders_chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#c3_orders',
    data: {
        columns: Data_columns,
        type : 'pie'
    },
    pie: {}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have clear picture where I had mistakes. Now working perfectly. Thanks.